# System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox different font per line

Tags: c#, fonts

I need a specific `font/style` for each `line` in a `RichTextBox`, the problem is that I am using `System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox` instead of `System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox` and it doesn't have the `.Select()` and `.SelectionFont()` `methods` as the Forms one have.

So my question is: How do I add a line in a `System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox` with a specific `font/style`?

Comment: do you have access to google..?  can you reach MSDN sites from where you are ..? if so look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: @irsog  have no idea, I just know that I am not using windows.forms

Comment: @DJKRAZE I have access to MSDN sites, however, I can't find anything there to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WPF `rich text box` in WPF accept [FlowDocument](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=flowdocument&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.aspx&ei=nx8OUZ_8F4rsrAfhiYCoDw&usg=AFQjCNFSwiDzYjuX8AfYRqvSnkctrEwHmA&bvm=bv.41867550,d.bmk). with `FlowDocument` you simply can set style for each line or world and ....
simple example:

```
  <RichTextBox >
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>
                    <Span FontSize="20">first line</Span>
                    <LineBreak></LineBreak>
                    <Span Foreground="Red" FontSize="20">sec line</Span>
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>
```

Comment: @Frederico Schardong:jast make a new wpf application and copy this part of code between window xmal code